# How can I convert Excel date columns to ISO Dates using string manipulation?

Tags: excel, string, datetime, excel-formula, iso

[image: Screenshot of Spreadsheet]

I have been practising Excel as I have been applying to apprenticeships.

During this task I've been trying to figure out how to use **string manipulation** to convert each date column (I2 and K2) to ISO Dates (DD-MM-YYYY). I created a new column to be able to store the converted ISO Dates (Column J).

This is what I came up with, with my current understanding of Excel:

`=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(I2,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(I2&" 1")),LEFT(I2,2)),"dd-mm-yyyy")`

**Here is my thought-process / reasoning:**
This formula assumes that the date in cell I2 is in the format "dd-mmm" (e.g., "07-Mar").

1. The DATEVALUE function converts the text string in cell I2 to a date value by appending " 1" to create a valid date ("07-Mar 1").
2. The MONTH function extracts the month from the date value obtained in the previous step.
3. The RIGHT function extracts the rightmost four characters from cell I2, which represents the year.
4. The LEFT function extracts the leftmost two characters from cell I2, representing the day.
5. The DATE function combines the year, month, and day values to create a new date value.
6. Finally, the TEXT function formats the new date value as "dd-mm-yyyy" (e.g., "07-03-2023").

However I would get the **#VALUE!** **Error**. I expected the first value of Column J (J2) would be 07-03-2023. The plan is to have the correct formula in Cell J2 and drag it down to completely fill Column J.

Any explanation to help me complete this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you show what is inside those cells in I and K columns instead of how they are formatted

Comment: How would I go about that? I noticed when I click on the cell under I or K -- it shows up in DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: Just select column, right click > Format cells > under number tab select Date from menu and pick your desired format or select Custom and type dd-mm-yyyy in Type field